# unable to add paginated list in asp.net ef core "Cannot implicitly convert type, An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

i have to add paginated list into my project. im following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0) tutorial. im actually can add paginate on other page, but i have to add ViewModels to make a validation for my search box. and if i use ViewModels, i cant use paginated list from the tutorials. the error says

> RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>' to 'ContosoUniversity.PaginatedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

this is my controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexProsesAsync(string sortOrder, StudentVM model, StudentVM currentFilter, int? pageNumber)
{
     ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
     ViewData["NameSortParm"] = sortOrder == "name" ? "name_desc" : "name";
     ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
     ViewData["FirstSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "first_desc" : "";

     if (model != null)
     {
         pageNumber = 1;
     }
     else
     {
        model = currentFilter;
     }

     ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = model.FirstMidName;
     ViewData["CurrentFilter2"] = model.LastName;
     ViewData["CurrentFilter3"] = model.EnrollmentDateFrom;
     ViewData["CurrentFilter3"] = model.EnrollmentDateUntil;

     var students = from s in _context.Students 
                       select s;

        // sorting // 
     students = sortOrder switch
     {
         "name" => students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName),// asc last name
         "name_desc" => students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName),//desc last name
         "first_desc" => students.OrderByDescending(s => s.FirstMidName),// desc first name
         "Date" => students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate),// asc date
         "date_desc" => students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate),// desc date
            _ => students.OrderBy(s => s.FirstMidName),// asc first name
      };

     // filtering
     if (model.EnrollmentDateFrom != null && model.EnrollmentDateUntil != null)
     {
         students = students.Where(s => s.EnrollmentDate >= model.EnrollmentDateFrom && s.EnrollmentDate <= model.EnrollmentDateUntil);
     }

     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LastName))
     {
         students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(model.LastName));
     }

     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FirstMidName))
     {
         students = students.Where(s => s.FirstMidName.Contains(model.FirstMidName));
     }

     ViewBag.students = students.ToList();
     int pageSize = 3;
     return View(await PaginatedList<Student>.CreateAsync(students.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
    }
```

my paginated list class

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;

    public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

this is on top of the view index.cshtml file

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.SchoolViewModels.StudentVM

@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Students";
   PaginatedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student> students = ViewBag.students;
 }
```

Comment: `var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).Cast<T>().ToListAsync();`

Comment: One issue is that your ViewBag.Students is being set to the unpaginated results.  You don't need the ViewBag there, just declare the @model as the PaginatedList<Student>. you're populating a model for the View using the paginated results but then in your view you're trying to set a variable "students" as the ViewBag.Students which is a List<Student>.

Comment: @StevePy is there any way to change/convert my List<Student> to paginated results? because i should keep the StudentVM class

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in supplied model to the razor.

razor file:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.SchoolViewModels.StudentVM */ It's required StudentVM */
```

Controller:

```
return View(await PaginatedList<Student>.CreateAsync(students.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
```

you supplied paginated Student model that is the reason for causing an error.

You will have to change in razor like `@model PaginatedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>` or you need to supplied only `StudentVM` from `Controller` like below:

```
 StudentVM model=new StudentVM();
 return view(model);
```

above changes will resolve your issue for sure.

you can check in your refer document [Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-paging-links)

Comment: where should i put the SchoolViewModels.StudentVM class?

Comment: From controller you need to supplied it to view. or Just changes razor view model with `@model PaginatedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>` and it will work for you

Comment: Looking at the example, yes the @model should be the paginated list. I believe the OP is mixing up examples or trying to combine a student list page /w a student detail/entry page. (StudentVM) These are separate views /w separate model needs.